# How do I separate elements from a list of permutations of a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, permutation

I want to create a program that gives all the permutations of a string and then out of list of strings and filter out ones that start with `'o'`. I want to find all permutations that start with `'o'`.

```
from itertools import permutations

x = list(permutations('hello'))
y = []

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    if x[i][0] == 'o':
         y.append(x)
         print(y)
```

I tried it with this code but its giving me a long list.

Answer (score 3):

You could filter out the ones that don't start with `o` (the `if ...[0] == 'o'` part) before building the complete list:

```
>>> y = [''.join(perm) for perm in permutations('hello') if perm[0] == 'o']
>>> y
['ohell', 'ohell', 'ohlel', 'ohlle', 'ohlel', 'ohlle', 'oehll', 'oehll', 
 'oelhl', 'oellh', 'oelhl', 'oellh', 'olhel', 'olhle', 'olehl', 'olelh', 
 'ollhe', 'olleh', 'olhel', 'olhle', 'olehl', 'olelh', 'ollhe', 'olleh']
```

The `str.join` converts the permutations to whole strings again. Remove it if you want it as `tuple` of `string`s.

---

To improve efficiency you could simply remove the `'o'` from `'hello'` and prepend it to every permutation of `'hell'` to get the same permutations:

```
>>> ['o{}'.format(''.join(perm)) for perm in permutations('hell')]
['ohell', 'ohell', 'ohlel', 'ohlle', 'ohlel', 'ohlle', 'oehll', 'oehll',
 'oelhl', 'oellh', 'oelhl', 'oellh', 'olhel', 'olhle', 'olehl', 'olelh', 
 'ollhe', 'olleh', 'olhel', 'olhle', 'olehl', 'olelh', 'ollhe', 'olleh']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    if x[i][0]=='o':
         y.append(x)
         print(y)
```

In this code, you put all the items in x list which means all permutation, into y list each time. That's why you had a long list.

Try this code.

```
from itertools import permutations
x=list(permutations('hello'))
y=[]
for i in x:
    if i[0]=='o':
        y.append(i)
print(y)
```

If you want to get unique list, just change

`x=list(permutations('hello'))`   to   `x=set(permutations('hello'))`